# Counting the number of digits in a natural number with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to return the number of digits of a Natural Number and I am almost there. I don't know how to count the digits though.

```
    private static int numberOfDigits(NaturalNumber n) {
    NaturalNumber zero = new NaturalNumber2(0);
    int a = 0;
    if (n.compareTo(zero) != 0) {
        a = n.divideBy10();
        numberOfDigits(n);           
    }
    return a;
}
```

I know I am returning the last remainder of n which is 0 but how do I count through the recursion?

Comment: Declare a counter outside of this function. Increment it in the function.

Comment: dont use recursion, use iteration

Comment: You're problem is that you're not saving the result of the recursive call.  The "answer" is the result from the recursive call +1.

Comment: I don't know anything about NaturalNumber class, but if you want to know number of digits in n number, calculate ceil(log10(n))

Comment: And how is `n.divideBy10()` defined?  Does it operate on n or does it return a new value.  What value does it return?

Comment: @HotLicks n returns the number divided by 10. Example: 123/10 = 12 However, I used a to keep the remainder so 'a' would equal the remainder of the division which is 3.

Comment: @AlexWien I know how to use loops but we are learning recursion with natural numbers

Answer (score 5):

If your current `n` is not zero, then you have one digit plus the number of digits in the number divided by 10.  Hint: you don't need the `a` variable.

```
if (n.compareTo(zero) != 0)
{
    // Return 1 for the last digit (1) + the rest.
    return 1 + numberOfDigits(n.divideBy10());
}
// Base case.
return 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't work since the method specified that numberOfDigits has a natural number parameter where n.divideBy10 return an int..!!

Comment: Is there a method that divides the `NaturalNumber` by 10 and returns another `NaturalNumber`?  That is required so that you can pass another `NaturalNumber` into your recursive call.

Comment: I can use `copyFrom` to copy a Natural Number to another

Comment: You can call n.divideBy10() first, then do the recursive call.

Comment: If you need a NaturalNumber then just do 
    
   'return 1 + numberOfDigits(new  NaturalNumber(n.divideBy10()));'

Answer (score 2):

```
private static int numberOfDigits(NaturalNumber n) {
    NaturalNumber zero = new NaturalNumber2(0);
    if (n.compareTo(zero) == 0) { 
        return 0;
    } else {
        n.divideBy10();
        return 1 + numberOfDigits(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tarik.  Can you please provide an explanation for the OP of how you arrived at your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cover zero, use the following.

```
private static int numberOfDigits(NaturalNumber n) {
    if(n < 10) return 1;
    return 1 + numberOfDigits(n/10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in C++

```
 int digits(int a, int c)
{
  int d = -1;
  if (a<10 && a>0)
  {
    c = c+1;
    cout << "No of digits = " << c << endl;
  }
  else if (a%10 == 0) // correct
  {
    d = a/10;
    c++;
    if (d == 0)
    {
       cout << "No of digits = " << c+2 << endl;
       return c;
    }
    else { digits(d,c); }
  }
  else if (a>10 && a%10 != 0)
  {
    d = a/10;
    c++;
    if (d == 0)
    {
       cout << "No of digits = " << c+2 << endl;
       return c;
    }
    else { digits(d,c); }

  }

  return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int c1 = 0;
    digits(n,c1);
    return 0;
}
```